# Посоветуйте решение для создания выпадающего стилизованного списка выбора

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, list, select

Необходимо реализовать выпадающий список выбора количества товаров, как на изображении.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, возможно, есть уже готовые решения (какие-то библиотеки), чтобы не изобретать велосипед. И какие из них наилучшие для моей задачи.

Требования:

- установить определенное количество товаров в селекте по умолчанию
- при нажатии на селект список плавно выезжает сверху
- в появившемся списке одновременно видно 4 итема, остальные доступны через скролл
- при выборе нужного количества товаров выбора подставляется в селект

Comment: Какой js фреймворк или библиотеку используете?

Comment: Немного не понял ваш комментарий. Мне нужно сделать кастомный селект. Поэтому и спрашиваю совета как его реализовать

Comment: Если вы используете бустрап, то будет одно решение, если jquery, то другое решение. Если реакт, то там свое, если ангулар, то другое, а если  vue, то третье. А если вообще без ничего, то другое решение.

Comment: Буду благодарен, если сможете подсказать решение без ничего (последний ваш вариант). Из того что смотрел в интернете: 1) компонент select из библиотеки bem-components (но там настолько сложно реализован селект, что его будет очень сложно стилизовать); 2) плагин jQuery Form Styler (но на Mac OS работает кастомные селект при доступе с клавиатуры). Хотелось бы, посмотреть на каком-то примере кастомный селект + кастомный скролл для прокрутки итетов селекта

Comment: почему именно селект? в чем привязка использовать именно селект ? почему не обычный div? как быстрый пример: https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/abzRbaz

Comment: Думаю, с клавиатуры к не му не будет доступа и возможности раскрыть список, сделать выбор, отправить потом выбранное значение

Comment: а зачем клавиатура? если там все равно выпадающий список? или необходима возможность пользователю вводить руками значение? отправить можно с чего угодно значение.

Comment: Нет вводить руками не нужно. Имелось в виду, чтобы к селекту был доступ с помощью перехода на него с помощью клавиши tab. Чтобы он функционировал как обычный встроенный селект, но при это со стилями как на изображении

Comment: К примеру, вот я нашел в интернете вполне приличный селект https://andrejgajdos.com/custom-select-dropdown/. Но он не ловит фокус и не фнкциональный с клавиатры. То есть он как декоративный

Comment: Вот еще понравился https://sitehere.ru/examples/03.09.2014/index.html. Но я не могу на него перейти табом(

Comment: Могу я рекомендовать [select2](https://select2.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabindex работает в следующем случае:

> The following elements support the tabindex attribute: A, AREA,
>   BUTTON, INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

Мы можем использовать любой из вышеперечисленных тэгов и применить к нему требуемый функционал.

**Input** будет использоваться просто для "хранения" передаваемого значения из кастомного списка. Чтобы мы могли применить "раскрытие списка" - будем использовать псевдо селектор **:focus**.

```js
const inputValue = document.querySelector('.input-value');
const inputArray = document.querySelectorAll('.input-array .item');

inputArray.forEach(x => {
 x.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  inputValue.value = e.target.innerText
 })
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ff6393;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 70px;
  font-size: .875rem;
}
.input-value {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: .875rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.input-value:focus {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.input-value:focus + .input-array {
  -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
          transform: translatex(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.input-array {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(10px);
          transform: translatey(10px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}
.input-array > * {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="input-value" type="text" value="0">
  <div class="input-array">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я очень вам благодарен!!!!!!! Поздно увидел ваш ответ, поэтому пришлось возится с jQuery Form Styler. Потратил кучу времени. Если вы знакомы с этим плагином, можете подсказать почему он перестал работать на этом сайте https://github.com/monsara/fizzyslim. Вчера работал, а сегодня нет